# How to get the current location in android application

Tags: android

When I touch on mapview; I get the longitute and latitute of that location. But, then again, when I touch another location, I do not get the longitute and latitute.

Can you please help to me solve this problem?

Comment: try to accept answers for your previous questions,.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-an)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/).